# MVC4 Async Controller Action not completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an async Action that gets called by jquery ajax request:

View:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("StartVerification", "Devices")",
    global: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(machineIds),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST'
    ...
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[SessionExpireFilter(Order = 1)]
[CheckPermissions(Order = 2)]
[AjaxMessagesFilter(Order = 3)]
[AsyncTimeout(30000, Order = 4)]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(TimeoutException), View = "TimeoutError", Order = 5)]
public async Task<JsonResult> StartVerification(ICollection<Machine> machines)
{
    Dictionary<int, bool> collection = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
    foreach (var machine in machines)
    {
        Response response = new Response();
        try
        {
            response = await this.deviceRepository.StartVerification(machine);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Success = false;
        }
        collection.Add(machine.MachineID, response.Success);
    }

    return this.Json(collection.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), y => y.Value));
}
```

Web service call:

```
public async Task<Response> StartVerification(Machine machine, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    WebService WebServiceForTask = WebServiceFactory.NewInstance;

    return await Task.Run(() => WebServiceForTask.StartVerificationForWebSite(machine.SiteID, machine.MachineID));
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when StartVerification action is executed which calls then queries a web service. The query for that result may take up to several seconds during which time a user may press a refresh button of their browser. What's the best way to handle this scenario and simply abort the call etc.

EDIT:
Maybe I'm asking the question wrong. The issue here is that when I StartVerification and hit refresh page F5 the page will NOT refresh until I get a response from webservice...and it looks like Action is not run async. I want it to work so that if a controller action is already called and waiting on a response from webservice I still should be able to simply browse away from the page that I'm calling the action from.

Comment: you can show ajax loading panel on beforeSend event and use complete event to hide the panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best way to handle this scenario and simply abort the call etc

You could subscribe to the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload) event before you start the AJAX request:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'There\'s an ongoing operation. If you leave this page you might lose some data';
};
```

and when the AJAX call completes remove the subscription to this event.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an `AsyncTimeout` attribute, you should [take a `CancellationToken` that represents that timeout](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CancelToken).

There is another `CancellationToken` that represents a user disconnecting early (`Response.ClientDisconnectedToken`). However, there is [currently a race condition on `ClientDisconnectedToken`](http://forums.asp.net/post/5339766.aspx) so I do not recommend using it with the current release of ASP.NET (4.5). The best policy right now is to honor the `AsyncTimeout` and just ignore early client disconnects.

However, if you really wanted to detect client disconnect, you could periodically poll for [`Response.IsClientConnected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx).